# Is there a review of lock free priority queues for single consumer multiple producer?

Tags: concurrency, scheduling, priority-queues

### Background

The task I have at hand is to write an event scheduler. From what I understood, it is basically a priority queue which needs to support concurrent insertions and single threaded delete operation of a key with highest value (in my case it is scheduled time). The worker thread will wait on a condition variable until the scheduled time of the next event and if there is a new maximum I need the worker thread to wake up and see if it needs to change the sleep time. There will be some threshold that if the current time and scheduled time have difference lower than the thresold, the producing thread will instead invoke the event synchroniously.

### My attempt

I thought about having a spin lock at every depth of a max heap. The heap will have a fixed size of power of two after creation. Then the worker thread will just wait on a condition variable with a lock holding the upmost level. When deleting, the worker thread will have to hold both locks for the uppermost level and the level beneath it.

The producing threads will have to start at the bottom and slowly progress up. This will sort of balance the load by introducing concurrency and splitting the wait time between levels. The main problem I have with this is that the bottom layers contain the most elements, thus progressing will be harder at the start.

I tried reading some of the recent papers, but most of them focus on skiplists, mounds and other data structures I have not seen yet. They usually glance over the datastructures and take knowledge of them for granted. Besides, they usually solve multiple producer *and* multiple consumer problem, the latter of which is different than mine.

### Question

Is there a good review paper which targets solutions for the problem I am trying to solve and is recent enough? Is there a state of the art solution for this problem?